# Convert a string (representing UTF-8 hex) to string

Tags: ruby, utf-8, string-decoding

I have a string in UTF-8 hex like this:

```
s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
```

I want to convert this into actual UTF-8 string. It should read:

> Your credit has gone below 5 dollars. If you have an Add-On or Bonus your resources will work until exhausted. To top up now visit vodafone.co.nz/topup

This works:

```
s.scan(/.{4}/).map { |a| [a.hex].pack('U') }.join
```

but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this: whether I should be using [Encoding#convert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Encoding/Converter.html#method-i-convert).

Comment: I don't think that is UTF-8 because `00` is a control character (NIL).  Looks more like a some kind of 16 bit encoding.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson doesn't UTF-8 have the ability of being 8 or 16-bit?

Comment: @vol7ron UTF-8 is a variable length encoding.   ASCII characters (0-127) are mapped to one byte, others are longer - up to 6 bytes.  If the leading bit is 0, then it is a one byte encoding of the code point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra `00`s suggest that the string is actually the hex representation of a [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) string, rather than UTF-8. Assuming that is the case the steps you need to carry out to get a UTF-8 string are first convert the string into the actual bytes the hex digits represents ([`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-pack) can be used for this), second mark it as being in the appropriate encoding with [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) (which looks like UTF-16BE) and finally use [`encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-encode) to convert it to UTF-8:

```
[s].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are extra null characters all along the string (it's valid, but wasteful), but you can try:

```
[s].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-8')
```

although, it seems "Your credit has gone below 5 dollars"...

The string prints with `puts`, but I can't read all the unicode characters on the terminal when the string is dumped.

Comment: It isn't UTF-8, so forcing the encoding to be UTF-8 is not correct.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson : It **IS** UTF-8 and the encoding is valid - check with `[s].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-8').valid_encoding?` ... Also, you can use `encode` instead of `force_encoding`, like this: `[s].pack('H*').encode('utf-8')`  - but why waste resources if the encoding is valid?

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding of 'Yo' is 0x596F, not 0x0059006F.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson , the answer still answers the question - even IF the string was malformed. I'm not sure, but I think you can always add null at the beginning of a value under 127, so Y become 0x0059 and o becomes 0x006F. The fact of the matter is that **the string passes validation** and prints correctly. Who am I to argue with the computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to use this on other oddly encoded strings, you could unpad the leading bytes:

```
[s.gsub(/..(..)/,'\1')].pack('H*')
```

Or use them:

```
s.gsub(/..../){|p|p.hex.chr}
```

---

If you want to use Encoding::Converter

```
ec = Encoding::Converter.new('UTF-16BE','UTF-8')     # save converter for reuse
ec.convert( [s].pack('H*') )                         # or:  ec.convert [s].pack'H*'
```

Comment: what if your string had a relevant double zero, such as `"s\n"` (== `200a` in hex)...? I would't remove those double zeros.

Comment: @Myst you are right, that was irresponsible and I've updated the answer :)